# how to get the config property details of kafka consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, logstash-forwarder

I'm new to kafka, Im facing a issue with consumer group
I have a logstash consumer group which created long ago now when I created a new Kafka topic starting with solr* it is automatically adding into kafta consumer group "logstash" If I create any other topic with some other name it is not adding into that consumer group so I would like to know how can I find the config properties information for a consumer group. I'm suspecting a config is provided for this consumer group at the time of creation. This is kafka 0.10

Answer (score 0):

**This might not be the best way to do this.**

You can simply restart any consumer in this consumer group. Kafka prints all the consumer config property used at the start of the application. If I remember correctly it prints all these logs at **INFO** level. So please adjust your logger to produce logs at INFO level or a level lower than `INFO` (probably `DEBUG` or `TRACE`) and you will be able to see what is the configuration property that it is using.